# Drupal8 change page title output

Tags: twig, title, drupal-8

How u can change the page title output?

```
<title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
```

in html.html.twig changes the mark/letter which creates:
`<pagetitle> | <sitename>`, but I want to change this order to `<sitename> | <pagetitle>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Twig reverse filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/reverse.html):

```
<title>{{ head_title|reverse|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal construct, by default, the page title such: [Entity-Title] | [Site Name].

**Titles on routes now can be set on various ways, depending on your use case.**
Previously (drupal-7) just `drupal_set_title()` was called in whatever place. The following use cases exist:

### Override title tag

You may override the title tag in the head of your HTML document using the `HOOK_preprocess_html`.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // Change the Title
  $variables['head_title']['title'] = 'Title';
  // Change the Suffix (sitename)
  $variables['head_title']['name'] = 'Suffix';
}
```

This use case should cover your issue. You can find plenty of other ways to override or change a page title checkout this other question/answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45561134/edit